# How can I create curve line with circle inside?

Tags: html, css

I wanted to create this curve over my circle.

[image: Image link]

```css
.oval {
  height: 32px;
  width: 32px;
  background-color: #EAF0F9;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 5px 3px 0 3px;
  text-align: center;
  /* padding: 2px 2px 2px 2px; */
}
```

```html
<div class="oval-curve"></div>
<div class="oval">1/3</div>
```

Comment: I can only imagine doing something like that using svg

Comment: What is next to the curve to the left and right? Your image has too small a clipping. Also a fully working example of the state of your work (with only the parts necessary) would be much appreciated

Comment: you can make this using css by making a css circle with a large border and transparent background. If you then cut off three quarters of the circle using a parent element with `overflow:hidden` you have an inverted circle, with which you can create the rounded border with. I hope this is understandable, it's a little tough to explain. I can make a snippet if you want, I just don't have the time right now.